# When should I put my code outside the export module, lifecycle hooks in a single file Vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm writing a code that needs to calculate some logics, for example, processing some arrays.

So, normally, a single file Vue component would look like:

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
import ...

// When should I put my code here?

export default {
  created: function() {
    // And what type of code I should put here?
  }    
}
</script>
```

When and what type of code should I put between `import` and `export`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can define some constant there. like this:

```
const THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT = 'thisIsAConstant'
```